# How do I remove a leaderstats value

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I Cant get rid of Mana, I tried to delete the folder and when I went back in the game the folder was still there what should I do?...

[image: a screenshot of the Explorer widget where the player has two leaderstats folders. Inside one is a NumberValue named Mana.]

CODE--

```lua
DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local myDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("myDataStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local Clicks = Instance.new('IntValue')
    Clicks.Name = "Clicks"
    Clicks.Parent = leaderstats 

    local Rebirths = Instance.new('IntValue')
    Rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    Rebirths.Parent = leaderstats

    local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
    
    -- Load Data

    local data
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        data = myDataStore:GetAsync(playerUserId)   
    end)    

    
    if success then
        Clicks.Value = data.Clicks
        Rebirths.Value = data.Rebirths
        -- Set our data equal to the current Clicks
    end 
    
    
end)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId       
    
    local data = {
        
        Clicks = player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value;
        Rebirths = player.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value;
    }

    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        myDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, data)
    end)
    if success then
        print("Data successfully saved!")
    else
        print("There was an error!")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
   
end)
```

Comment: search your code and find the code that added it, and remove that code. If you don't post any of your code in your question, there's not much more anyone here can do to help. Please update your question with the code that creates your leaderstats.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question with code. However, this isn't the code that adds the Mana value. Are there any other scripts that are creating Mana? Is there anything that is calling `require(123456)` but with some other number?

Comment: No there is nothing called require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find the script that creates the `leaderstat` you could use script like the following to delete the extra `leaderstats` folder containing the `Mana value`. I wouldn't recommend this because the extra `leaderstat` has to be generated somewhere and it's best to just get rid of the script creating it.

Anyway you could try this: Add the following code to the `ServerScriptService`

```
game.Players.OnPlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    wait(5) -- to wait for the script that adds the leaderstats to run
    for _, child in ipairs(player:GetChildren()) do
        if child.Name == "leaderstats" then
           for _, value in ipairs(child:GetChildren()) do
               if value.Name == "Mana" then
                   child:Destroy()
               end
           end
        end
    end
end)
```

What the above script does is it checks if a `leaderstats` folder inside the player exists with the value `Mana`, if it does, it will destroy the `leaderstats` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted above is not adding the extra leaderstats folder and value `mana`. User the search in the explorer to find any scripts in your game. Just type `script` into your search. Then open each file in your game hit `Ctl + F` on your keyboard and find `Mana` in each script.

[image]

Why this could happen? There are many assets from the toolbox that come bundled with scripts which could be one cause of your problem, but it can also happen because of plugins you have installed which add leaderstats to your game.

Comment: I have disabled everything in my game and Mana is still their

Comment: What should I do?